# How to find a string in char Array without using string functions?(c++)

Tags: c++

I have following code:

```
char x[30]="computer";
char y[30]="put";
```

I want to find whether "put" is present in "computer" and print its position.No string functions allowed.

Comment: `std::strstr` or `std::search` might be useful.

Comment: Use std::string, not char arrays!

Answer (score 2):

## Library function(c++ style)

```
std::string a = "computer", b = "put";
bool found = a.find(b) != std::string::npos;
```

## Without Library function(c style)

I assume you don't hope to get terrible complexity, so [KMP](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm) is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

In C++ you could use strings and string::find

With char arrays tho,

```
if (strstr(x, y) != NULL) {
    // contains
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In C++ you have the find method on string :

```
 std::string str ("computer"); std::string str2 ("put");

 std::size_t found = str.find(str2);
```

if found = -1, 2nd string isn't in first.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/

Answer (score -1):

Since you are using C++ you can use std::string:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

const std::string stringToSearch("computer");
const std::string stringToFind("put");

if (stringToSearch.find(stringToFind) == std::string::npos) {
    std::cout << "not found\n";
} else {
    std::cout << "found \n";
}
```